# Smarty: is it possible to call a PHP function (from the controller class) inside the template?

Tags: php, function, smarty

I created a function in the controller class that needs to be used inside the template (because the template it rendered many times (each template is a post on the website, and they will be all displayed with different values in the newsfeed). Is there a way to call it on a smarty variable?
Say you created a function in the controller:

```
public function foo($bar){
       $bar++;
       return $bar;
}
```

And then in the template:

`{$smarbar|foo}` or something similar

Comment: Do you mean is it possible to make the function static so bar is incremented on each call?

Comment: No no, I just want to know if it is possible to call a PHP function in a smarty template file. The function is just an example. The rest of the text is explaining why I would want to do this.

Comment: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/plugins.functions.tpl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could register a modifier that will call a given method of a class:

```
class SomeClass {
    public function someMethod($value)
    {
        // return modified value
    }
}

$smarty = new Smarty();

$smarty->registerPlugin('modifier', 'myModifier', array('SomeClass', 'someMethod'));
// or
$instance = new SomeClass();
$smarty->registerPlugin('modifier', 'myModifier', array($instance, 'someMethod'));
```

and now you can use this inside your template:

```
{$someVar|myModifier}
```

Here's the [registerPlugin](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.register.plugin.tpl) documentation.

Comment: Just a warning, calling methods in a static context when they're not declared static is now deprecated with the release of 5.6 earlier today.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just pipe the function on template

{$myvar|my_function)

Comment: This actually works. Those who downvoting please explain the bad side of it

Answer (score 1):

Everything depends on your needs but if you simply want to use code like this you may assign object to Smarty and use its methods.

For example in PHP you can do:

```
class Controller
{
    public function foo($bar)
    {
        $bar++;
        return $bar;
    }
}

$smarty->assign('a', new Controller);
```

In Smarty you can do:

```
{$a->foo(5)} {$a->foo(15)}
```

And you will get:

> 6 16

as output.

Comment: What, if I want to submit a smarty array value as parameter? Such as `{$a->foo({$array.key})}` ? Is it possible?