# Passing a smarty array value to php object...?

Tags: php, arrays, object, smarty3

In [Smarty: is it possible to call a PHP function (from the controller class) inside the template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25551384/smarty-is-it-possible-to-call-a-php-function-from-the-controller-class-inside/25586121#25586121) there is explained, how to call class methods out of template files.

You nee to assign the object like

`$smarty->assign('a', new Controller);`

and you can use it like

`{$a->foo(5)}`

But what, if I want to pass a smarty array value as parameter? It should be something like this:

```
{foreach from=$dataset item=data}
   {$a->foo($data.id)}
{/foreach}
```

for sure, this won't work. But how can this issue be handled?

Answer (score 0):

[Chapter 15. Advanced Features](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/advanced.features.tpl)

This is what you need?